# A script/batch to load a website, clear cache, and repeat

Tags: batch-file

How can I do this with a Windows 7 computer?

It will

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Fully load a website (like cnn.com or yahoo.com)
3. Close the browser
4. Clear the cache
5. Repeat from Step 1

Comment: Whats the purpose of this batch file?  Because I feel like you just want to make a DDOS like batch

Comment: It will be used to capture traffic between a test PC and our Internet proxy server. I was thinking more of a .bat file that will just run on the client PC

Answer (score 1):

Without using anything not in operative system, the easiest way is to use vbscript. Create a .vbs file with the following content. Adjust as needed.

It just a loops over a Navigate, Clean

```
    Do While True
        WScript.Echo "Navigating"
        DoNavigation "http://www.yahoo.com"
        WScript.Echo "Cleaning"
        DoCleanCache
    Loop

Sub DoCleanCache
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess  24271", 0, true 
End Sub

Sub DoNavigation( URL )
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = 0
    Wait IE

    IE.Navigate URL
    Wait IE

    IE.Quit
End Sub 

Sub Wait( oIE )
Dim loops 
    loops = 200
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While oIE.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 100
        loops = loops - 1
        If loops = 0 Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: can this .vbs script run directly from the client PC through an executable or .bat file?

Comment: `cscript.exe navigateCleanAndAgain.vbs`